# Customer custom attributes do not save data to customer_entity table

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-attribute, savedata

I'm creating a rest API and I need to add a custom columns to the *customer_entity* table and save the value in that fields within API request.

Сreated new attributes in the *customer_entity* table using *UpgradeSchema*:

```
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0', '<=')) {
        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('customer_entity'),
            'phone',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'length' => 100,
                'comment' => 'Phone'
            ]
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('customer_entity'),
            'full_name',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'length' => 100,
                'comment' => 'Full Name'
            ]
        );
    }

    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

The above code created two new fields in *customer_entity* table. And now I have a function that accepts data from the rest api request and creates a customer, customer is created with this code, but it does not save values to *customer_entity* table for *phone* and *full_name* fields.

*use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;*

```
public function __construct(
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerInterfaceFactory,

) {
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->customerInterfaceFactory = $customerInterfaceFactory;
}

public function createCustomer( string $fullName, string $phone, string $password )
{
    try {
        $customer = $this->customerInterfaceFactory->create();
        $customer->setEmail(uniqid( '', true ) . '@auto.gmail.com');

        $customer->setFirstname($fullName);
        $customer->setLastname($fullName);


        // Set custom attributes
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('phone', $phone);
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('full_name', $fullName);

        // Save customer
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->save($customer, $password);

        return 'Customer created successfully ' . $customer->getId();
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        return 'Error creating customer: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

If you know, please tell me how I can put a value in a customer custom attributes when creating a customer.

Answer (score 0):

I will share my code for your related issue. please understand and try to it. my code is to get data API from third-party Guzzle and that value is saved in the "customer_entity" table.

/var/www/html/myproject/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">

<route method="GET" url="/V1/faqdata/getguzzledata/">
    <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\FaqInterface" method="getApiData"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>

<route method="POST" url="/V1/faqdata/innsertguzzledata/">
    <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\FaqInterface" method="setData"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

/var/www/html/myproject/app/code/Vendor/Module/Api/FaqInterface.php

```
<?php
    
namespace Vendor\Module\Api;

interface FaqInterface
{
    public function getApiData();

    /**
     * @return string
     */

    public function setData($data);
}
```

/var/www/html/myproject/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\FaqInterface.php" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Api\Faq"/>
</config>
```

/var/www/html/myproject/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Api/Faq.php

```
<?php 
 namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Api;

 use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
 use GuzzleHttp\Client;
 use GuzzleHttp\ClientFactory;
 use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
 use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
 use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ResponseFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
 use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request;

class Faq implements \Vendor\Module\Api\FaqInterface
{

private $customerFactory;
protected $response = ['success' => false];
protected $messageManager;
/**
 * API request URL
 */
const API_REQUEST_URI = 'https://dummyjson.com/';

/**
 * API request endpoint
 */
const API_REQUEST_ENDPOINT = 'users';

/**
 * @var ResponseFactory
 */
private $responseFactory;

/**
 * @var ClientFactory
 */
private $clientFactory;
/**
 * @var Json
 */
private $json;

/**
 * GitApiService constructor
 *
 * @param ClientFactory $clientFactory
 * @param ResponseFactory $responseFactory
 * @param Json $json
 */

public function __construct(
\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
ClientFactory $clientFactory,
ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
Json $json

)
{
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->clientFactory = $clientFactory;
    $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;
    $this->json = $json;
}


/**
 * Fetch some data from API
 */
public function getApiData()
{
    $response = $this->doRequest(static::API_REQUEST_ENDPOINT);
    $status = $response->getStatusCode(); // 200 status code
    $responseBody = $response->getBody();
    $responseContent = $responseBody->getContents(); // here you will have the API response in JSON format
    $var = [];
    if($status == 200){
        $products = $this->json->unserialize($responseContent);
        foreach ($products['users'] as $key => $product){
            $var[] = [
                'firstName' => $product['firstName'],
                'lastName' => $product['lastName'],
                'maidenName' => $product['maidenName'],
                'email' => $product['email'],
                'birthDate' => $product['birthDate'],
                'gender' => $product['gender']
            ];

            // $var['firstName'] = $product['firstName'];
            // $var['lastName'] = $product['lastName'];
            // $var['maidenName'] = $product['maidenName'];
           
            // $var['email'] = $product['email'];
            // $var['birthDate'] = $product['birthDate'];
            // $var['cardExpire'] = $product['bank']['cardExpire'];
            // $var['cardNumber'] = $product['bank']['cardNumber'];
            // $var['cardType'] = $product['bank']['cardType'];
            // $var['currency'] = $product['bank']['currency'];
            // $var['company-address'] = $product['company']['address']['address'];
            // $var['postalCode'] = $product['company']['address']['postalCode'];
        }   
    }
    return $var;
}



/**
 * Do API request with provided params
 *
 * @param string $uriEndpoint
 * @param array $params
 * @param string $requestMethod
 *
 * @return Response
 */
private function doRequest(
    string $uriEndpoint,
    array $params = [],
    string $requestMethod = Request::HTTP_METHOD_GET
): Response {
    /** @var Client $client */
    $client = $this->clientFactory->create(['config' => [
        'base_uri' => self::API_REQUEST_URI
    ]]);

    try {
        $response = $client->request(
            $requestMethod,
            $uriEndpoint,
            $params
        );
    } catch (GuzzleException $exception) {
        /** @var Response $response */
        $response = $this->responseFactory->create([
            'status' => $exception->getCode(),
            'reason' => $exception->getMessage()
        ]);
    }

    return $response;
}


/**
 * Fetch some data from API
 */
public function setData($data)
{
    $test = $this->getApiData();
    
    try {
        foreach($test as $check){
            
           
            $insertData = $this->customerFactory->create();
            $insertData->setFirstname($check['firstName']);
            $insertData->setLastname($check['lastName']);
            $insertData->setMiddlename($check['maidenName']);
            $insertData->setEmail($check['email']);
            $insertData->setDob($check['birthDate']);
            if($check['gender'] == "male"){
                $insertData->setGender(1);
            }
            elseif($check['gender'] == "female") {
                $insertData->setGender(2);
            }
            $insertData->save();
        }
        $response = ['success' => true, 'message' => 'successfully saved'];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
    }
    return $response;
}
}
```

I will share the below screenshot for Postman API get data.

[image]

backend side customer image before

[image]

database screenshot before save the data.
[image]

insert data in Postman successfully

[image]

after api response is successful the Magento backend side saves data.

[image]

After API response save the data customer_entity table.

[image]

I will share all my backend and API data and my database screenshot share. i hope you that is help for you.